# Flattening list type in dataframe column results in 'float' object is not iterable` type error

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a column called 'player_traits' which is made up of lists and I want to be able to find the count of elements using `Counter`. I found a way to [flatten the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707117/count-of-elements-in-lists-within-pandas-data-frame) and count them but when I try to flatten it out, I get a `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

I've checked the type() of an instance of the column and have verified they are lists, so I'm not sure why there's an error saying float objects are not iterable.

Here is an example of the column:

df['player_traits']:

```
0        [Finesse Shot,  Speed Dribbler,  One Club Play]
1          [Diver,  Beat Offside Trap,  Selfish,  Flair]
2                   [Diver,  Flair,  Technical Dribbler]
```

And here is my code (in my Jupyter notebook) which produces the error:

```
trait_series = df['player_traits']
flat_list = pd.Series([item for sublist in trait_series for item in sublist])
Counter(flat_list)
```

I've also checked to make sure that `trait_series` is also a series, and it is. What is going wrong? Is there another way to flatten the lists and count the elements?

Edit: I've been having trouble updating Python version. Is there a way to flatten the list without using .explode()?

SOLVED: instead of using .explode(), I found some code that would work for flattening lists by filtering out the nulls:

```
non_nan_df = df[df['player_traits'].isnull() == False]

player_traits = np.array([item for lst in
non_nan_df['player_traits'].values for item in lst])

Counter(player_traits)
```

Comment: Look at `df['player_traits'].isnull().sum()`. My guess is that's non-zero so your real DataFrame has missing data. `NaN` is a float so you get an error on that row because it's trying to do `for item in NaN`, which makes no sense. You probably just want `df['player_traits'].explode()`

Comment: Oh, I see that makes sense. I looked up .explode() and that is helpful to know, but `df['player_traits'].explode()` returns a `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`. Is there a reason for that? Because w3resource and other resources say it's quite literally a pandas Series function.

Comment: You probably have an older version of pandas. That feature was added a few major releases ago

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.